# Where to write the power with a logarithmic function?

Tags: logarithms

This might be a simple question, but where would I write the power if I had a logarithmic function?

Instinctively I would write it as $\log^y(x)$. But I'm not sure if this is correct. Should I be writing $(\log(x))^y$ instead?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Those two are the same, but just be careful to note that $(\log_{b}(a))^c\neq\log_{b}(a^c)$

Comment: Okay thanks, so these two notations should both be acceptable on say an official exam?

Comment: Yes it should be understood. See this if you want to read more: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150546/what-does-log2x-mean

Comment: What's acceptable on an "official" exam is up to the official who gets to mark the exam, and that's the person you should ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $(\log x)^y$; you don't need more parentheses than that. There are problems with writing $\log^n\!x$. By analogy with (say) $\cos^n\!x$, it might be interpreted as $(\log x)^n$. However, it might also be taken to mean (quite logically) $\log...\log x$ (where there are $n$ applications of the logarithmic function).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that into consideration!