# How limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \log^bn }{n^a} = 0$

Tags: limits

For $a>0$ and $b>0$,

I tried like this

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \log^bn }{n^a}  = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\log n)^b }{n^a}$

and then by applying L'Hopital's Rule

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ b*\log n*1/n }{an^(a-1)}$

Its seems even though I apply L'Hopital's Rule it is giving me indeterminate form.

Any help how above limit becomes 0.

Comment: What are $a,b$? Are they any real number? Because if so, the statement is false. Are they nonnegative numbers? The statement is still false. It may be true if they are both positive real numbers.

Comment: It's true when a is positive. b can be any number

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin good point.

Comment: Yes $a>0$ and $b >0$

Comment: The tag refer to limit without l’Hopital. Are interested on that or are you looking for a solution by l’Hopital?

Comment: -1 because I took help?

Comment: No, not at all. All downvotes are caused by a lack of quality, determined by the Community.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the integral form of the logarithm:
$$\log(x) = \int_1^x \frac 1t \, dt,\ x > 0.$$
It is routine to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x} = 0$ because for $x > 1$ you have
$$0 \le \frac{\log x}{x} = \frac 1x \int_1^{\sqrt x} \frac 1t \, dt + \frac 1x \int_{\sqrt x}^x \frac 1t \, dt \le \frac {(\sqrt x -1)}x + \frac{(x-\sqrt x)}{x \sqrt x} \le \frac{2}{\sqrt x}$$ and can apply the squeeze theorem.

If $a > 0$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^a} = 0$ because $x^a \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and 
$$\frac{\log x}{x^a} = \frac 1a \frac{\log x^a}{x^a} \to 0.$$ 
If $b > 0$ too then
$$\frac{(\log x)^b}{x^a} = \left( \frac{\log x}{x^{a/b}} \right)^b \to 0.$$
If $b \le 0$ then $(\log x)^b \le 1$ as soon as $x \ge e$ and the result is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Let consider the limit

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ \log^bx }{x^a}$$

with $a,b>0$ and let $x^a=e^y\to \infty$ with $y\to \infty$ therefore

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ \log^bx }{x^a}=\lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{ \log^be^{y/a} }{e^{y}}=\lim_{y \to \infty}\frac1{a^b}\frac{ y^b }{e^{y}}=0$$

which follow by l'Hopital or by the fact that eventually $e^{y}=1+y+\frac12y^2+\ldots \ge y^{2b}$ and then

$$0\le \frac{ y^b }{e^{y}} \le \frac{ y^b }{y^{2b}}=\frac1{ y^b }\to 0$$

Therefore we can conclude that

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ \log^bx }{x^a}=0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \log^bn }{n^a} = 0$$

Comment: $\log^bn$ is meaningless, what is it suppose to be ? $\log n^b $ or $(\log n)^b$

Comment: @Arjang For what I've always seen $\log^bn$ is the standard notation for $(\log n)^b$.

Comment: from what I have seen $\log^bn$ is standard notation for $\log \log \log \cdots \log n $ where $\log$ is applied $b$ number of times.

Comment: @Arjang please refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150546/505767

Comment: why are you allowed to replace x^a with e^y?

Comment: @Lupos We have that $$x^a=e^y \iff y=\log (x^a)=a\log x$$ which allows the substitution.

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the fundamental inequality satisfied by $\log x$ namely $$0\leq\log x\leq x-1,\,x\geq 1\tag{1}$$ Let $c=a/b>0$ and choose $d$ such that $0<d<c$. Replacing $x$ by $x^d$ in $(1)$ we get $$0\leq d\log x\leq x^d-1<x^d,\,x\geq 1$$ which is same as $$0\leq \log x<\frac{x^d} {d}$$ and this implies that $$0\leq \frac{\log x} {x^c} <\frac{1}{dx^{c-d}},\,x\geq 1$$ Noting that $c-d>0$ and taking limits of the above inequality as $x\to \infty $ we get $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log x} {x^c} =0$$ via Squeeze Theorem. Raising the above to power $b$ we get $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\log x)^{b}} {x^a} =0$$

---

The fundamental inequality $(1)$ looks very simple, but is one of the defining characteristics of the logarithm function. More formally

> **Theorem**: If $f:\mathbb{R} ^{+} \to \mathbb{R} $ satisfies $f(x) \leq x-1,\,\forall x>0$ and $f(xy) =f(x) +f(y), \, \forall x, y>0$ then $f(x) =\log x$.

Comment: Very nice derivation! How can we justify the foundamental inequality without advanced tools such as derivatives, Taylor? Mayby by $$x=e^y\implies y\le e^y-1$$ and deriving the latter from $e^n\ge n$ which can be shown by induction?

Comment: @gimusi : The inequality is an immediate consequence of any definition of $\log x$ you choose. For the definition based on integral just note that if $1/t\leq 1$ if $t\geq 1$ and integrating this wrt $t$ on $[1,x]$ we get the inequality. For definition $\log x=\lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{1/n}-1)$ prove the fact that sequence $n(x^{1/n}-1)$ is decreasing. If you define log as inverse of exp then you need to establish $e^x\geq 1+x$ which can be done using any definition of $e^x$.

Comment: I have upvoted your reference/answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $b>0$:

With L'Hospital's Rule, you get:

$$\dfrac{b\left(\log n\right)^{b-1}\dfrac{1}{n}}{an^{a-1}} = \dfrac{b\log^{b-1} n}{an^a} = \dfrac{b}{a}\cdot \dfrac{\log^{b-1} n}{n^a}$$

If you apply L'Hospital's Rule $\lceil b \rceil$ times, you get:

$$\dfrac{\lceil b \rceil !}{a^{\lceil b \rceil}} \cdot \dfrac{\log^{b-\lceil b \rceil} n}{n^a}$$

This is no longer an indeterminate form.

If $b\le 0$, then it was not an indeterminate form to begin with.