# Why do powers of $\log x$ grow slower than powers of $x$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I just came across the statement that any power of $\log(x)$ grows much slower than any positive power of $x$, i.e. $(\log(x))^a$ = $o(x^b)$ for arbitrary $a$ and $b >0$. How can I prove it?

Comment: Related is the recent question [Why does $\log^{100}(n)$ grow asymptotically slower than $n^{7/8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3980233/13130). Note that the answer by Bernard is exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Oh! thanks a lot!