# Why is the logarithm squared in this equation? $\log^2x-3\log x=\log x^2-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I just don't understand why the log is squared
$$\log^2x-3\log x=\log x^2-4$$

Comment: $(\log(x))^2$ is often represented as $\log^2(x)$. Notice that it is a quadratic equation in terms of $\log(x)$

Comment: See also: [What does $\log^{2}{x}$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150546)

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

The notation stands for: $\log^2 x=(\log x)(\log x)$.

Then use that $\log x^2=2\log x$ and let $\log x=t$ to obtain a quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $log x=y$, then
$$log^2 x-3log x=log x^2-4$$
$$y^2-3y=2y-4$$
$$y^2-5y+4=0$$
$$(y-1)(y-4)=0$$
$y=1$  or  $y=4$
$$log  x=1$$  or  $$log  x=4$$

Hence
$x=10 $ or $x=10000$